# Angular 9 - Bloquear que escriban un espacio al inicio de un input text

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

tengo un input text y necesito impedirle al usuario que escriba un espacio en blanco al inicio del texto. Cuando el input text está vacío, me funciona bien, pero si el usuario ingresa un texto y luego vuelve a la primera posicion y me inserta un espacio, se lo permite...
Esto es lo que tengo en el html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Buscá la empresa de servicios" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" (keydown.space)="noEspaciosAlPrincipio($event)">
```

y en el componente.ts tengo lo siguiente:

```
noEspaciosAlPrincipio(event: Event) {
    if (!this.value.length || this.empresaForm.get('empresa').value.length === 0){
      this.empresaForm.get('empresa').setErrors({'firstBlank': true});
      this.empresaForm.get('empresa').markAsTouched();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Si me pueden dar una mano se los agradezco. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

podes intentarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<input  type="text" (keyup.space)="noEspaciosAlPrincipio()" [(ngModel)]="search">
```

y en el componentente:

```
  search = '';
  noEspaciosAlPrincipio() {
    let stringArr = this.search.split(/(\s+)/);
    if (stringArr[0] === '') {
    this.search = '';

    for (let i = 2; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
     this.search += stringArr[i];
    }
  }
 }
```

De esta forma podes quitar los espacios al inicio, espero te sirva.

Comment: el comportamiento es exactamente igual a lo que tengo. NO FUNCIONA porque me está permitiendo agregar comentarios delante. Imaginate que escribis MUNICIPIO, con las flechas del teclado vas hacia adelante a la primera posicion e insertás espacios...te deja insertarlos y necesito que no me deje

Comment: Entendi mal el problema, mil disculpas. Actualize mi respuesta usando el metodo TRIM(), en el ejemplo uso NgModel pero puede ser un formulario reactivo o una variable de template con viewchid

Comment: Tampoco me sirve, los caracteres al final los preciso. Es una funcionalidad particular, no puedo quitar los espacios del final...solo los del principio pero debo mantener intacto el resto

Comment: Realice una ultima actualización! talvez esta si te pueda funcionar.

Comment: la verdad que no se comporta como necesito, porque si bien quita los espacios, dentro del input text el cursor se va moviendo hacia adelante...necesito que se anule la entrada y no permita escribir los espacios que estén adelante